# Не отображается объект на сцене через Sprite Renderer

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: В синих гранях не отображается объект]

В синих гранях не отображается объект.

Comment: Возможно стоит заменить `OrderInLayer` на побольше

Comment: Спасибо!! Это не помогает

Comment: А что в итоге помогло?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько причин:

1. Неправильно задан "Order in  Layer" у самого объекта или у фона.
2. Объект или рамка слишком малы.
3. Объект находиться не в канвасе.
4. В пункте Color, ползунок прозрачности стоит на 0.
5. Плохой спрайт
6. Возможно беды с координатой Z у объектов.